# angular 4 process response from interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am not even sure how to describe the problem ...

Since we started using Interceptor the error handling has been moved from the component to the interceptor, but now I have no idea how to display a "Login failed" message on the component, because the error is basically unknown there.

I guess I just understand Angular too little at this point, so I could really need some help atm.